# How to compute a digital signature on a Smartcard?

Tags: smartcard, sign, apdu

So I'm pretty new to smartcards and I'm trying to compute a signature over some random bytes. The operating system on the card is cardos v4.3 . I am able to use the PKCS#15 Format and the ISO 7816 standard.

My workflow to compute the signature is as follows:

1. select SigG application APDU= 00 A4 01 0C 02 1F FF 00. status = 90 00
2. verify Sig. Pin in the current DF APDU= 00 20 00 81 08 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 00   status = 90 00
3. trying to sign 40 random Bytes with PSO_CDS APDU=  00 2A 9E 9A 08 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 .... 28(hex) 00 status = 6A88

The smartcard is in a freshly reset.

Am I missing a command or a prerequisite I need to satisfy or something else?
What is the general workflow when signing a hash which was computed with for example openssl?

I know that for PSO_CDS there must be a Current Security Environment where a valid PSO_PrivateKey must be specified, but I don't understand how to incorporate this into the commandflow.

I am planning to create a c++-function which will get a hash, compute the signature with the smartcard and then return the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to compute a signature. Because PSO_CDS doesn't really worked for me, I did it this way:

1. Select the SigG Application/DF.
2. Made an manage security environment set (mse set), where I specified the CON component (which is the PSO Private Key in the Application) off the current security environment.
3. verified the pin with the Pin object in the SigG Application.
4. Computed the signature with PSO_DEC. When using PSO_DEC you need to provide an extended apdu, because the command field has to contain a padded 256 Byte hashvalue and with normal apdu's it is only possible to have an command field up to 255 Bytes on my card.

Comment: It is not exactly recommend, to use PSO_DEC for creating a signature, because PKCS padding is different there and could become a security issue. What you describe under (4) is quite independent from the card at hand; that is, how short APDUs work.

Comment: How could that become an security issue? 
I know that (4) ist quite independent from the card, I just wanted to provide a relative complete explanation what I did to get things working. So that also beginners are able to understand everything.

Comment: Encryption uses PKCS Block Type 2 padding, which pads with random bytes. So your signature is not unique, which a standard RSA-signature with block type 1 would be. Depending on the strictness of the verify signature implementation, your signature could be simply considered as non-conforming due to wrong padding. Block type 1 also makes sure, that nearly all bits before the hash value are set, so the standard exponentiation algorithm is pretty stressed; for the most significant bits this is important, but for details you should ask elsewhere (cryptography or information security).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the card does not know, which key to use. This is due to the correctly observed lack of a meaningful current security environment. Since Perform Security Environment (short: PSO) has no standardized means of specifying the key to use, this has to be set-up earlier by providing the security environment with that information, e. g. via Manage Security Environment (see below).

The easiest way for providing the key reference is, to create a persistent Security Environment with the ID 1 in the same DF as your key, since this is loaded (or restored) automatically during SELECT (FILE) of the DF, otherwise you have to send Manage Security Environment (short MSE) in Restore mode manually or in SET mode (volatile for this session). (Whichever Security Environment you use, it has to contain the reference to a private key within digital signature template.) Whether you do the MSE RESTORE directly after selection of the DF, before the PIN verification or at any moment in between is your choice, but it has to be active when sending the PSO command.

40 bytes seems not to be the length opf a typical hash value, so take care to set up the algorithm properly to include hashing.

Comment: Aren't you confusing MSE:SET (Manage Security Environment) and PSO (Perform Security Operation) in the first section of your answer? It's a bit hastily written it seems.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I find your comment  confusing. I tried to rephrase for clarification, but everything seemd correct.

Comment: It still reads " Perform Security Environment" in the first section. I know that ISO 7816-4 (related) standards are a complete and utter mess, but isn't the Object ID at least specified in the PKCS#15? So it is mainly an issue of which command format to use; I've personally never used MSE: RESTORE I think (trying to remember, so many years...), only MSE:SET.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I am now able to send successfull a MSE SET command (APDU= 00 22 41 b6 03 84 01 02 00). The statuscode when I run the command is 90 00. But then, when I try to compute the signature in the next step, it still says 6A 88 (referenced data not found). But with the MSE SET I am setting the secret key for computation. Feels like something is still wrong with the MSE SET. 02 is the ID of my secret key object inside the DF SigG. Do you know how to reference my key correctly in the MSE SET command? 

I am also using know a proper hash for the computation.

Comment: I would try DST frame tag=b6, len =6, containing : 84/01/id for private key and 95/01/40 usage qualifier (all numbers hex).

Comment: can you give me an example how to use the qualifier in the apdu? Just behind the 84/01/02 ? And also I think, the Private Key might not be created when reseting the card. Do you guys know which commands I have to use in which order to create an rsa 2048-bit key in the DF? Or should I create a new question for this?